# Using variables in the preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor-directive

which global variable can be used in the preprocessor directive
file.cpp

```
int variable = 1;
#if variable >= 1
    int a = 0;
#else 
    int a = 1;
#endif
```

or

file.cpp

```
const int variable = 1;
#if variable >= 1
    int a = 0;
#else 
    int a = 1;
#endif
```

or 
file.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
// extern in variable; in the header.h
#if variable >= 1
    int a = 0;
#else 
    int a = 1;
#endif
```

What are the rules which governs using the variables in the proprocessor directive?
If a variable which can be consant folded, can it be used in the #if/#elif#else directives?

Comment: Preprocessor directives and variables are completely different. You can't do this, at all.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't understand C++! It has its own interpretation.

Comment: Only #define symbols work in #if

Answer (score 12):

Sorry, you can't do this at all. Variables are not visible to the preprocessor. The preprocessor is at its heart a text manipulator. The only values it can see are ones defined with `#define`, not variables.

Comment: i used to think that const can be used as a replacement for #define for example, #define TEST 1 or const int TEST = 1, can we use these as #if TEST == 1 .... #endif

Comment: No.  You can only use a `const` instead of a `#define` if you *don't* need to use the constant in `#if`.  Often this is fine.  Other times all you care about in `#if` is whether or not the constant has *some* value, so for instance you may see `#define EPERM EPERM` in `<errno.h>` and the numeric value is set with an `enum`.  That lets you do `#ifdef EPERM` or `#if defined EPERM` but not `#if EPERM == 23`.

Answer (score 2):

Only macros defined with `#define` will have their expected value in an `#if`.  All other symbols (more precisely, all identifiers that remain on an `#if` line after macro expansion, except `defined` and, in C++, certain "alternative spellings" of arithmetic operators, such as `and`, `or`, `bitand`, `bitor`, and `compl`) are interpreted as having the value 0.