# How to pass a variable value to a Token pasting operator(##) in C

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

The below code is failing when I am trying to pass a variable to concate macro.

```
#define token_1 5
#define concate(i) taken_##i

    int main()
    {
        int x = 1;
        printf("%d", concat(x));
    }
```

But it passes and prints 5 when I directly give concate(1). 
How to pass a variable value to a token pasting operator?

Comment: You can't. The preprocessor does only simple text replacement, there won't be any notion of variables values at runtime.

Comment: What would be the workaround to get this working for the above case?

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaDurgavajjala https://stackoverflow.com/a/52262411/1084774

Comment: @PSkocick This duplicate mark is a miss.  VKD is asking for runtime preprocessing; indirection isn't going to help.